# Url rewriting in asp.net 3.5 with multiple querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I have a travel related web application in which my url looks like

```
MyTravel/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8
```

and

```
MyTravel/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8&DeptF=ND
```

Now I want url rewriting on my application  like

```
MyTravel/Tour/Goa/new-year-goa
```

here goa and new year goa are fetched by pid and cid values.

Help me.

Thanks in advance

[EDIT: Reformation]

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting can be done as follows,

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();

    if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Tour/Goa/new-year-goa");
    }
    else if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8&DeptF=ND")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Tour/Goa/new-year-goa"); 
        //This can be something else according to your requirements.
    }
}
```

You can look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Or else you can modify your `web.config` to achieve the goal,

here is the sample,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

<configSections>
<section name="rewriter"  
         requirePermission="false" 
     type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
</configSections>

<system.web>

<httpModules>
  <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
</httpModules>

</system.web>

<rewriter>
 <rewrite url="~/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8" to="~/Tour/Goa/new-year-goa" />
 //Some other re-writers to achieve specific requirements.
</rewriter>  

</configuration>
```

[EDIT: Following Can be one solution]

ok. So as you are saying you need to check `pid` and `cid` so redirect accordingly,

One way to achieve this is below,

- `Request.QueryString("Pid")` and `Request.QueryString("Cid")`
- store them into some variables,
- check those variables with some switch...case mechanism and according to the passed condition set the path using `Context.ReWritePath("Your Specified Path")`

The other way to do this is using database,

- create a table containing three columns, `pid`, `cid`, and `location_path`
- Now get the `cid` and `pid` using above mentioned `Request.QueryString`
- using sql query, select the location from the table which matchs with the `cid` and `pid` fetched by `Request.QueryString` and set it using Context.ReWritePath

Hopefully this is clear to you now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I am not sure about SEO, you have to test it live to confirm.

Comment: thank sir, Actually I have a lot of packages so ids(Pid=2&Cid=8) will me more than 200, so please tell me how dynamically(using regular expression/pattern matching) I achieve this goal, I am not want handle it as hardcode.

Comment: This `fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8")` will check whether the url contains `Pid=2&Cid=8` or not. In our case, you need to specify all the `cids` and `pids` if you want them to redirect to their corresponding urls.. Regular expression will allow you to check whether there is pid and cid or not, but to redirect, your have to compare them for your packages and redirect them accordingly...

Comment: Sir actually i want that if pid is 33(agra) and cid is 540(tajmahal) then it looks like MyTravel/Tour/agra/tajmahal and if there is no querystring then it simply moves to home. So how it is possible can u provide me a sample code please its very urgent.